# pass textbox as query criteria

Tags: ms-access, textbox, in-clause

I've hit following problem:

I have a table in MS Access 2013 [mytable] and form [LSIP]. There is textbox **strQueryDates** on the form which represents a string with *dates* ("28/04/2015 12:00:00","30/04/2015 12:00:00")

I make a query to find all events from [mytable] starting in within *dates* of **strQueryDates** :

```
SELECT [mytable].Title, [mytable].[Start Time]
FROM [mytable]
WHERE (cstr(([mytable].[Start Time])) In (Forms![LSIP]![strQueryDates].Text))
```

Unfortunately this does not work. But if I replace with the actual value of **strQueryDates**:

```
SELECT [mytable].Title, [mytable].[Start Time]
FROM [mytable]
WHERE (cstr(([mytable].[Start Time])) In ("28/04/2015 12:00:00","30/04/2015 12:00:00"))
```

It works perfectly.
Any idea what might be the reason and how to workaround the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
WHERE (Format([mytable].[Start Time]), "dd\/mm\/yyyy") & " 12:00:00") In ([Forms]![LSIP]![strQueryDates])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Unfortunately the result is the same. Formatting does not seem to be the problem. I suspect a limitation in "In" clause and the textbox.

Comment: Sorry, a space was missing.

Comment: nope, it's not the space that is the problem :)
I turned up side down my entire logic and opted for another approach.
Thanks.